# Не могу установить discord-components

Tags: python

ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement discord-components (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for discord-components

```
from discord_components import DiscordComponents, Button, ButtonStyle
```

Comment: Пожалуйста, исправьте вопрос, чтобы он отражал конкретную проблему с достаточным количеством деталей для возможности дать адекватный ответ.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

тоже столкнулся с такой проблемой при развёртывании своего бота, который раньше работал стабильно. Единственное решение, которое я нашел, — это вручную установить сам код библиотеки. Установите библиотеку с github https://github.com/kiki7000/discord.py-components/tree/master/discord_components в папку ваших библиотек, пример Ubuntu /usr/lib/python3.10/, на Windows же эта папка скорее всего находится здесь C:\Users\ИМЯ ПОЛЬЗОВАТЕЛЯ\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\Lib